# Gnuplot: hide plots by default?

Tags: hide, gnuplot, visibility

I'm Using Gnuplot 4.6 (I'll change to 5.0 if required) with the wxt terminal on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a single window with a single plot with multiple curves like this:

`plot 'file1' u 1:2 w l, '' u 1:3 w lp, 'file2' w i, '' u 1:3 wp pt 7` etc

I can click the keys of curves to hide/show them. Can I make some of them hidden by default?

This is useful as I am comparing computation outputs and use a lot of labels and different lines/points/impulses etc for different data, and the graph gets really messy. And many times I only need some content for a few seconds at the time, so I end up hiding most plots, to show them when needed.

Any advice is welcome! Cheers /J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There had indeed been a discussion about such a feature, i.e. change the visibility of plots via some option, see http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/message/31315515/. As far as I know, that wasn't implemented yet.

If it helps you, there are some hot keys which allow you to change the visibility of many plots:

```
show bind
```

gives the following hot keys

```
...
i              `builtin-invert-plot-visibilities`
...
V              `builtin-set-plots-invisible`
v              `builtin-set-plots-visible`
```

So, you can invert the visibility of all plots (`i`), hide all plots (`V`), and show all plots (`v`).

Comment: That's pretty much second to perfect. Thanks a lot!